# Openlayers proj not defined issue

Tags: babeljs, openlayers, browserify, proj

Openlayers (5.1.3) app bundled with browserify and babel:

```
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import {bbox} from 'ol/loadingstrategy';
import proj from 'ol/proj';
...
    var source = new VectorSource({
        loader: function( extent, resolution, projection ) {
            var crs = config.crs || "EPSG:4326";
            var url = '/rest/table/' + config.table;
            var newExtent = proj.transformExtent( extent, proj.get( crs ), proj.get('EPSG:3857'));
...
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transformExtent' of undefined
```

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "watchify -g [ babelify --presets [ \"@babel/preset-env\" ] ] client/js/main.js -o public/bundle.js -v ",
```

Why?

Comment: In OL5 you need to register proj4 http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj_proj4.html

Comment: proj4 will come later :) For now, the problem is 'proj' is undefined, which is why the first failure is the call to transformExtent()

Comment: You are mixing OL4 and OL5 syntaxes. Try

`import {get as getProjection, transformExtent} from 'ol/proj.js';`

with

`var newExtent = transformExtent( extent, getProjection( crs ), getProjection('EPSG:3857'));`

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I'll update the code and post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mike https://stackoverflow.com/users/10118270/mike - here's the updated code:

```
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import {bbox} from 'ol/loadingstrategy';
import {get as getProjection, transformExtent} from 'ol/proj';
...
    var source = new VectorSource({
        loader: function( extent, resolution, projection ) {
            var crs = config.crs || "EPSG:4326";
            var url = '/rest/table/' + config.table;
            var newExtent = transformExtent( extent, getProjection('EPSG:3857'), getProjection( crs ));
...
```

I also had the source and dest projections the wrong way round.